# ADK 2012 and Android

Tags: android, arduino, adk

Following the steps [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html#dev) to start developing android accessories with ADK 2012, there is this step:

> Copy the < adk-source-download >/adk2012/board/library/ADK2 directory
>   and its contents into your sketchbook/libraries/ directory, so that
>   you create a sketchbook/libraries/ADK2 directory.

This is my very first time working with ADK 2012 so I'm not quiet sure what I'm supposed to do in this step, so maybe if someone could clarify it more for me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ADK2012 source must be downloaded and compiled using Git. This separate from the zip files you also download from the Google page. The zip file contains the Arudio IDE only.. If using windows you will need to pay special attention to the "note:"

From<[Downloading the ADK Source](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html#src-download)>:

Download and install Git for your development system.
Download and setup the repo tool, as described on the Android open source project site.

**Note: Developers using Windows must use a Linux compatibility package, such as cygwin, to install and run repo. Within your compatibility environment, you must install curl, git and python to be able to download and use the repo tool.**

In a terminal window, create a new directory for the downloaded source files, initialize and synchronize a local repository:

```
$> mkdir android-accessories
$> cd android-accessories
$> repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/accessories/manifest
$> repo sync
```

This is the hardest part.... If you make this this far you are on the path for success!

You should now have a folder called android-accessories with sub-folders /adk2012/board/library/ADK
Now you need to copy the ADK folder to your Arduio libraries folder

You need to find the location of your "sketchbook/libraries" folder. This folder was created when you installed the Arduino software. In Arduino click --> File --> Preferences. The first item should be "Sketchbook location". This folder will have sub-folder called "libraries.

Once you copy the ADK folder to library you can move to set 4 (restart Arduio) on the google help page

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I moved the entire android-accessories folder into the library folder of Arduino and I was able to open the example 'demokit' so there's that but, I got the Arduino plugin for Eclipse. Should these libraries be used in Eclipse, now? Also, I have today posted a new question about an error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161715/arduino-error-in-eclipse). Could you take a look at that question, please?